# Batch file to connect mysql and run commands

Tags: mysql

I want to run a batch file from windows, which connect to mysql server on different machine, and run a procedure from database or run a sql file which is sitting in my local machine.

is there's a way to do it. I know that I need the below script in my batch file to run sql commands but I believe it's only work when you run the batch file in mysql server enviornment.

do I have to define the server info (e.g IP address & port)
how do I do that

any help would be appricated

Thanks

mysql --user=XXX --password=XXXX --database=XXX < XXX.sql

Answer (score 8):

if your MySQL Server (`mysqld`) is running on the same host as your MySQL client application ([`mysql`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html)), your command

```
mysql --user=XXX --password=XXXX --database=XXX < XXX.sql
```

works.

If your server is on another host (as in your case), you have to add the hostname:

```
mysql --host=IP.ADDR.HERE --port=3306 --user=XXX --password=XXXX --database=XXX < XXX.sql
```

The `XXX.sql` file is on the same host as your MySQL Client.

Offcourse your server has to accept connections from other hosts (bind-address defined, no skip-networking, and the correct user@host privileges defined) so check your server configuration.

Comment: do I have to specify the path of .sql file, sql file sits in the same windows folder where the batch file is and server is on another host.

Comment: Yeah, you have to specify the path. If it is in the same folder, and your batch file is called from that folder (or the `start in` parameter is set correctly, which it is by default), it will work. If not, you can add the complete path `C:\Windows\XXX.SQL` or use `%WINDIR%\XXX.SQL`.

Comment: Hi Konerak,
this is what is in batch file
mysql --host=XXX.XXX.XXX.XX --port=3306 --user=XXX --password=XXX --database=XXX < C:\Batchfile\XXX.sql
but its not working, do I have to write something else in the batch file, because my batch file conatin the above line and that's it
I have tried putting qouation marks with path but didn't work

Comment: Does it work without a batchfile? If you just open a command prompt and use the `mysql ... `, can you connect? What happens when you do `mysql ... <XXX.sql`, does that work? We need more info :)

Comment: 'mysql' is not recognize as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Comment: First get the commandline working, then try batchfiles. If `mysql` is not recognized, you need to install the MySQL commandline client (mysql.exe) and then modify your %PATH% to include the .exe. You might want to turn that into a [separate StackOverflow Question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @Ibrahim: It prompts for the password when you do --password? Are you sure the password is correct then? What happens when you create a `.my.cnf` in your homedir with `password=XXXX`?

Answer (score 1):

This way the sql statement can be given inside the batch file.

```
mysql --host=ipaddress --port=3306 -u root -ppassword dbname -e "insert into emp ('id', 'name') values (1, 'hawk')"
```

Answer (score 0):

*do I have to define the server info (e.g IP address & port) how do I do that*

You need to set port if it is not 3306.
You need to set host if you want to specify user you want to connect, as you know MySQL user has a name and host - 'user1'@'**host_name**'.

See the manual -
[The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html)